# How to sort a split string

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In google sheets I have this string:

```
salmon,fries,peas,coleslaw,onion,garlic,chicken,pancetta,creme fraiche,onion,garlic,chicken,pancetta,creme fraiche,onion,garlic,chicken,pancetta,creme fraiche,gf pizza,gf pizza,pepperoni pizza
```

I would like to split it by the `,` character, sort it and `textjoin` the result.

The overall function I'm working with is this:

```
=textjoin(",", true, sort(split(textjoin(",",true,$D$2:$D$22), ","), 1, true))
```

So it looks to me like the `sort` function call is not working, but obviously the input to it is not a range of cells but a list (?) of strings produced by splitting a combination of strings.

The inner-most `textjoin` is required because the cells being joined contain lists of strings  separated by `,` characters. I am trying to sort *every* string from every cell in one large list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
=textjoin(",", true, sort(transpose(split(textjoin(",",true,$D$2:$D$22), ",")), 1, true))
```

`SORT` only sorts by row and in the case of `SPLIT` it returns a single row. All we have to do is `TRANSPOSE` that so that it can be sorted correctly.

Comment: ...thus a simple `=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, SORT($D$2:$D$22))` will return the same result

Comment: No, it doesn't.